# Javascript size and download speed

Tags: php

I have a bunch of javascript/css/img sources. I want to calculate their size and how long it takes for me to download them. Is that possible using cURL? Would like to see a suggestion on what cURL function should i use for this. Or shoud i use something else for this?

Comment: It is almost impossible to calculate a duration of download. Because of toooo many factors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about curl in this context, but a useful tool for that is the "Why Slow" or YSlow extension for Firefox :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

It analyses every resource donwloaded by your page, a dpresents it in a very useful manner, with the milliseconds used by each resource etc. It also gives hints how you can improve the results.

YSlow can also be integrated in Firebug.

Of course, what it gives you depends strongly on the connection you use, and the result will differ depending on each connection used by each client. However it gives you a good general idea of which resources are using up brandwith, where bottlenecks are etc.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not do a precalculation with curl.**

But you can **post-calculate** using [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) **after** you do the request.

It will return an array of information about the request.

The keys of this array you will need are:

CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME - Total transaction time in seconds for last transfer
CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME - Time in seconds until name resolving was complete
CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME - Time in seconds it took to establish the connection
CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds from start until just before file transfer begins
CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds until the first byte is about to be transferred

And for the size:

CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD - Total number of bytes uploaded
CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD - Total number of bytes downloaded

Hope it helps.